# Kann man "dem Kampf bereit" sein?

Tags: grammatical-case

Ist es falsch, so zu schreiben:

> Ich bin dem Kampf bereit.

und muss es stattdessen:

> Ich bin zum Kampf bereit.

sein? Falls ja, warum könnte das Dativ allein nicht genügen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Bereit sein* kann man *zu etwas* oder *für etwas*. Ein einfacher Dativ reicht da nicht, und dafür gibt es keinen guten Grund. Das ist halt einfach so.

> Ich bin zum Kampf bereit.
> Ich bin für den Kampf bereit.
> <strike>Ich bin dem Kampf bereit.</strike>

Es gab laut Grimms Wörterbuch "früher" eine Verwendung mit Genitiv (*des Kampfes bereit*). Die ist also schon zu der Zeit, als der Eintrag im Wörterbuch erschien (19. Jahrhundert) nicht mehr aktuell.

Das Wörterbuch nennt ein altes poetisches Beispiel mit Dativ, dort wird aber *bereit* eigentlich im Sinn des Partizips *bereitet* benutzt, und das kann mit Dativ stehen:

> nach diesem leben ist bereit
> ein leben uns in ewigkeit.
> *(Claudius bzw. [Luther](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wir_glauben_all_an_einen_Gott))*

Mit dem eigentlichen Wort *bereit* ist das nicht möglich, auch nicht  gehoben oder literarisch. Siehe auch [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bereit).

Comment: Oder, wie Muddern sacht: "Wer brauchen braucht, ohne zu zu gebrauchen, ist zu nichts zu gebrauchen."

Comment: In literarischer Sprache geht es auch nicht?

Comment: Ich habe die Antwort ergänzt.

Comment: Also "**des** Kampfes bereit" ist aber richtig?

Comment: Nein, der Gebrauch mit dem Genitiv ist mE nicht mehr korrekt.